# Is there a way to run only selective examples from a cucumber scenario outline?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-serenity

I have a Cucumber `.feature` file with scenario outline like below.

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |    12 |   5 |    7 |
    |    20 |   5 |   15 |
```

Is there a way to run only specific row(s) from the examples table during a test run?

Right now, I need to split this into two scenario outlines and tag one of them as `@ignore` to accomplish this.

Does cucumber provide a way to filter examples during execution, maybe based on a column in the example table?

Answer (score 2):

I found a pretty neat way to do this in the Cucumber docs after I read them extra-carefully.

The answer is directly in this [page](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java)

It is possible to tag specific examples in the way given below:

```
Scenario Outline: Steps will run conditionally if tagged
  Given user is logged in
  When user clicks <link>
  Then user will be logged out

  @mobile
  Examples:
    | link                  |
    | logout link on mobile |

  @desktop
  Examples:
    | link                   |
    | logout link on desktop |
```

This serves my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Cucumber with JUnit 5, you can use:

```
@SelectClasspathResource(value = "com/example/application.feature", line = 42)
```

This will run the example on line 42.

If you're using Cucumber with JUnit 4, you can use:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "com/example/application.feature:42")
```

Though as you are also using Serenity, neither may work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @m-p-korstanje  
Is there a documentation pointing to `SelectClasspathResource` option you detailed above?

Comment: I reckon https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine and https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-suite-engine should get you pretty  far.

Comment: Or the skeleton project, https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton